# Displaying data using Bootstrap modal/angularjs from asp.net webapi

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, bootstrap-modal

I'm new to bootstrap. I want to do CRUD operations on the employee data from asp.net WebAPI using Bootstrap-Modal. I'm able to display the data from webapi to angularJS using a table(ng-repeat). In every row, at the end, I've three buttons VIEW, DELETE and EDIT and another outside the table ADD.

I want, whenever a user clicks on the ADD, VIEW, DELETE and EDIT button, a bootstrap modal should pop up and we should be able to perform CRUD operations.
I've tried many instances but no luck on how to get the data on Modal. Please help.
The code is as follows:

WEBAPI:

```
     public class EmployeeService
```

{
    SampleDatabaseEntities sampleDBEntities = new SampleDatabaseEntities();

```
//ADD USER
public int saveEmployee(EmployeeTable employeeTable)
{

    sampleDBEntities.EmployeeTables.Add(employeeTable);
    sampleDBEntities.SaveChanges();
    return employeeTable.E_ID;

}

public EmployeeTable getEmployeeById(int id)
{

    return sampleDBEntities.EmployeeTables.Find(id);
}

public List<EmployeeTable> getEmployees()
{
    return sampleDBEntities.EmployeeTables.ToList();
}


public void updateEmployee(int x, EmployeeTable employeeTable)
{
   if (employeeTable.E_ID == x)
    {
        sampleDBEntities.Entry(employeeTable).State = EntityState.Modified;
        sampleDBEntities.SaveChanges();
    }


}

public void deleteEmployee(int id)
{


    var employee = sampleDBEntities.EmployeeTables.Find(id);
    if(employee !=null)
    { 
        sampleDBEntities.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        sampleDBEntities.SaveChanges();

    }

}
```

Angular Service:

```
angular.module('mainApp', []).
        factory('employeeService', function ($http) {
            var baseAddress = 'http://localhost:53254/api/employee/';
            //var baseAddress = 'http://localhost:49595/MobileService/api/UserService/';
            var url = "";

            return {
                getEmployeesList: function () {
                    url = baseAddress;
                    return $http.get(url);
                },
                getUser: function (employee) {
                    url = baseAddress + "Get/" + employee.E_id;
                    return $http.get(url);
                },
                addUser: function (employee) {
                    url = baseAddress + "post";
                    return $http.post(url, employee);
                },
                deleteUser: function (employee) {
                    url = baseAddress + "Delete/" + employee.E_Id;
                    return $http.delete(url);
                },
                updateUser: function (employee) {
                    url = baseAddress + "put/" + employee.E_Id;
                    return $http.put(url, employee);
                }
            };
        });
```

Angular Controller:

```
angular.module('mainApp')
    .controller('getEmployeeCrl', ['$scope', 'employeeService', function ($scope, employeeService) {

        employeeService.getEmployeesList().then(function (response) {

            $scope.employees = response.data;
        }, function (err) {
            $scope.errMessage = "Something wrong with server. Please try again.";
        })

    }]);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mainApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../mainApp.js"></script>
    <script src="../Utilities/ConstantsFactory.js"></script>
    <script src="../Services/EmployeeService.js"></script>
    <script src="../Controllers/EmployeeController.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="getEmployeeCrl">
    <div>
        <h2 style="text-align:center; color:darkblue">PROJECT 51</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div style="background-color:dimgray;color:white;padding:20px;">
            <input type="button" value="Go to Employees" class="btn btn-info" />
            <input type="button" value="Go to Clients" class="btn btn-info" style="width:145px" />
            <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn btn-primary" value="Add" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add Data" style="float:right; width:50px"></button>
        </div>
        <br />
        <table class="table table-bordered table table-condensed" ng-hide="!employees">
            <thead style="background-color:palevioletred">
                <tr style="text-decoration:solid;color:darkblue;">
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Job</th>
                    <th>Hire Date</th>
                    <th>Manager</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Commission</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Edit/Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees ">
                    <td>{{emp.E_ID}}</td>
                    <td>{{emp.E_NAME}}</td>
                    <td>{{emp.E_JOB}}</td>
                    <td>{{emp.HIRE_DATE}}</td>
                    <td>{{emp.MANAGER_ID}}</td>
                    <td>{{emp.SALARY}}</td>
                    <td>{{emp.COMMISSION}}</td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="width:170px">
                        <input type="button" ng-model="emp.E_Id"  value="View" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:70px" />
                        <input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:70px" />
                        <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:70px" />
                    </td>

                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="!employees">{{errMessage}} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" ng-show="!employees"></span></p>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make use of Bootstrap Modal for CRUD operations

Comment: Where is your angular code that calls the API's? Are you receiving errors anywhere? We need more info

Comment: I'm sorry.. please disregard the above code. I'm posting all the codes below:

Comment: any one could help me with this please??

Comment: And what is the issue you are having